# Fatal error with learnpress wordpress site on azure server

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I was running my Wordpress site on Azure Web Services server, and everything was running smoothly. I use Learnpress plugins for a learning app and Eduma theme. Yesterday, we wanted to upgrade the server plan in Azure, and suddenly a critical error message appeared. I could not access wordpress even with safe links. Today this error message is visible on the site:

> Warning: require_once(inc/Filters/class-lp-filter.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php on line 244
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'inc/Filters/class-lp-filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php:244 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php(219): LearnPress->include_files_global() #1 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php(167): LearnPress->includes() #2 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php(895): LearnPress->__construct() #3 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php(937): LearnPress::instance() #4 /var/www/wordpress/wp-settings.php(462): include_once('/var/www/wordpr...') #5 /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php(137): require_once('/var/www/wordpr...') #6 /var/www/wordpress/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/wordpr...') #7 /var/www/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/wordpr...') #8 /var/www/wordpress/index.php(17): require('/var/www/wordpr...') #9 {main} thrown in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/learnpress/learnpress.php on line 244

I tried changing the file path, as well as deleting the whole Learnpress folder using FTP, but its like it isn't listening to me. It uploads the changes but the same error persists. How can I fix it?

We also tried reverting to a backup through Azure but again nothing happens.

Comment: Not entirely sure what help you are expecting from developers here - you need to place the file in the error message at the expected location.

Comment: If you think your environment isn't functioning properly that isn't really a programming question or something we can realistically help with from another website, in a Q&A format (see also the [tour] and [ask] to learn how stackoverflow works). I would imagine you need to talk to Microsoft Support if you cannot even restore backups etc